# count and group by two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two database tables and i want to order my posts by votes, i tried the query method below but it is not working as i wanted.  my tables are like this :

```
posts    
postID  Title  Desc 
10
11
12

votes
votesid  postvote  value              
1         10        0
2         10        1
3         10        1
4         12        1
```

I want query like this ( postvotes has PostID and when people vote it raising ) and if value is equal to 1 count number of postvote column.

I want this output

post 10 has 2 votes
post 11 has 0 votes
post 12 has 1 vote

I tried this code but not working

```
SELECT i.postID, i.Title, i.Desc, r.postvote, COUNT(r.postvote) AS mediaCnt          
FROM posts i 
LEFT JOIN votes r ON i.postID = r.postvote 
GROUP BY i.postID 
ORDER BY mediaCnt DESC
```

where i do mistake ?

Comment: Define "not working". What results are you getting now and what are the expected results? You originally tagged as "php" but no code to support the question.

Comment: I want to receive how many votes has for posts, ( postvote value is same with postID ) i want it to count same values and show the number

Comment: See my edited answer and I hope, it will work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you wanted. See the query:

```
SELECT i.postID, i.Title, i.[Desc], COUNT(r.postvote) AS mediaCnt
FROM posts i LEFT JOIN votes r ON i.postID = r.postvote 
WHERE r.value = 1
GROUP BY i.postID, i.Title, i.[Desc], r.postvote
ORDER BY mediaCnt DESC
```

Output:

[image: count_output]

Comment: for 4 votes shows 47 and 3 votes 40 , 1 vote is 40 too

Comment: It works fine on my side. Did you try the exact code that I provided?

Comment: I try with my code because i have more values like title, desc, image, etc.. should i use all for GROUP BY at the end ? and how about , do i need to use  ORDER BY countAll  DESC?

Comment: Got the issue. Desc and i.Desc conflicts in the query as Desc could be said as a query property. I just replaced it with i.[Desc] and it works fine now. Try and let me know. When I used this i.Desc, it gives syntax error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Desc'`. Next time, write this error too and will help others to make it work :)

Comment: Thank you AT-2016 i have changed name of Desc column as postDesc :) but i tried exactly your code, still receiving strange numbers it is not counting as i wanted, i will try more if you tried this code and i will let u know

Comment: Both the codes work for me I mean your and mine. I don't understand what's the issue actually? :D

Comment: ok your code works fine, it is my fault because in votes table, near k.postvote there is one more column and name is value, if value is 1 this is showing as vote.

Comment: so i need this now when counting k.votes  if k.value is equal to 1 .. do u have any idea?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Could you elaborate a little? Seems like your requirement is changed.

Comment: i need this, if value column is equal to 1 

 votesvotesid  postvote  value             
1         10         0
2         10         1
3         10         1
4         12         1

so out put i need like this :

postID   countAll
10         2    
12         1

Comment: If value column has value 1 then? Again not clear. Better edit your post and include the requirement in it.

Comment: Edited my question on the top

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 1):

the only thing you can select is the columns you use under group by or some function like count sum min max. So try to use a sub select that already contains the columns you want then do a left join.

```
SELECT 
    i.postID, i.Title, i.Desc, r.postvote, COUNT(r.postvote) AS mediaCnt    
FROM posts i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.postvote, COUNT(r.postvote) AS mediaCnt from votes r  GROUP BY r.postvote) AS r
ON i.postID = r.postvote 
ORDER BY mediaCnt DESC
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'r.postvote' in 'field list'

Comment: now it worked but it is only showing one post not others